# AOP, Spring 4 MVC and @Around annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

Today I'm trying to manage some AOP stuff with Spring 4 and I have a problem with @Around annotation. It works only after pointcut and behave like @After annotation. What is worse - combination @Before and @Around annotation effects only in calling a method after pointcut.

Combination @After and @Before works fine. To be honest - i have no idea why it works like that.

I also trying some mockito to detect calling AOP method but it's not working.

I have configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.package.to.aop" })
public class AOPConfiguration {}
```

AOP class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SmartLoggerAspect {

    @After("execution(* my.package.to.specific.function."
            + "repositories.PagingAndSortingBookRepository.findAll("
            + "org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)  )")
    public void afterPage(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\nCALLED AFTER: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }

    @Before("execution(* my.package.to.specific.function."
            + "repositories.PagingAndSortingBookRepository.findAll("
            + "org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)  )")
    public void beforePage(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\nCALLED BEFORE: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }

    @Around("execution(* my.package.to.specific.function."
            + "repositories.PagingAndSortingBookRepository.findAll("
            + "org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)  )")
    public void aroundPage(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\nCALLED AROUND: " +   joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

And I made a unitTest for it

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JPAConfig.class, AOPConfiguration.class })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
public class AspectTest {

    @Autowired
    PagingAndSortingBookRepository pagingAndSortingRepo;
    @Autowired
    SmartLoggerAspect smartLoggerAspect;

    JoinPoint joinPoint;


    @Test
    public void pagingTest(){
        pagingAndSortingRepo.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 1));
        //verify(smartLoggerAspect, times(1)).afterPage(joinPoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `@Before`+`@After` __and__ `@Around` advices too? Why don't you try combing the advices in one `@Around` advice?

Comment: Because I'm a beginner and trying many ways to use AOP. When I comment aBefore and aAfter function and leave aAround only, still i got the same problem

Comment: What do you mean with 'It works only after pointcut [...]'?

Comment: It means message shows only after calling method, not before (as it is in spring documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is using `JoinPoint` instead of `ProceedindJoinPoint` for the `around` advice method.

Also you need to invoke `pjp.proceed` method in the around advice.

Quoting from [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

> The first parameter of the advice method must be of type ProceedingJoinPoint. Within the body of the advice, calling proceed() on the ProceedingJoinPoint causes the underlying method to execute.

Comment: No i edited this function

@Around("execution(* my.package.to.specific.function."
   + "repositories.PagingAndSortingBookRepository.findAll("
   + "org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)  )")
 public void aroundPage(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable{
  proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
  
  System.out.println("\n\n\n\nCALLED AROUND: " + proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
 }

And still got the same problem